# display background across whole menu bar

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS for my horizontal menu:

```
#nav>li {
    float:left
}
#nav li:hover ul {
    position:absolute;
     display:block;
}
#nav {
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%; 
    list-style:none;
}
#nav li a {
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 8px;
    margin:0;
    background: #666666; 
    border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #EEEEEE;
    width:80px;
    border-right:1px solid #F36F25;
}
#nav li a:hover, #nav li a.active {
    background: #F36F25; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#nav li ul {
    display: none;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
}
#nav li ul li {
    margin-top:0;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-left:-40px;
}
#nav li ul li a {
    background: #EEEEEE;
    color:#666666;
    border:1px solid #EEEEEE;
    width:145px;
}
#nav li ul li a:hover {
    background: #EEEEEE;
    color:#f36f25;
    border:1px solid #f36f25;
}
```

I want to add a background colour for 100% width of the page, i tried adding `background-color:#666666;` to

```
#nav
```

but that didnt work, here is a fiddle of the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/39Rdw/

i want the menu to be 100% width of the page

Comment: have you found the `80px` you set for `#nav li a` ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `<li>` tag under `#nav` floated left which is keeps `#nav` from wrapping around it's inner content.  If you add the [clearfix css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix) to your css and add this class you to your `#nav` '` it will force it wrap around the inner content and should give you the effect you're looking for.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39Rdw/12/)

Also `<li>` are meant to be wrapped in `<ul>` tags.  You might want to change any `<li>`s not wrapped in a `<ul>` to a `<div>`.

Comment: how can i make the menu 100% so there are no gaps left and right?

Comment: There is no magic bullet to do that as the menu would need to flow with all of the different monitor sizes.  There is plenty examples dynamic layouts on the web or SO that can get you in the right direction.  The other is to fake it. Figure out a width, center the menu and removed the left and right most borders so that `#nav` will span the entire width with the background color and menu blends in...  but again this is just my opinion.  Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

add this to CSS file

```
 body{
   background:#666666;
   width:100%;
 }
```

Comment: well that clearly just does the whole page which isnt what i said

Comment: hmm,sorry didnt understand.. When you said you want background color of 100% width I thougt you wanted it all that color. So you want just the nav background section that color?

Comment: yeah just the nav background